# iPhone app will will not install from webpage (enterprise developer)

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

This is probably something very simple and I'm missing it - however we have an Enterprise developer license and are looking to release an app in house.

I have created the .ipa file and the .plist file as well as an index.html file.

I am hosting those on a certed server (https) - so I should be good there, but when I navigate to the site and click on the link I've made nothing happens.

My index.html file contains a link to the .plist file and it looks like this:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://54miles.ourorganization.org/54%20Miles.plist" id="text">Version 1.1 of the 54 Miles App</a>
```

In the plist is the following:

```
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://54miles.ourorganization.org/54%20Miles.ipa</string>
                </dict>
```

The app has a space between 54 and Miles and it seems to be what is hanging me up here.  Not sure the best way to make it happen as my understanding was I just create the .html file with the link to the .plist - once that gets tapped - it asks to install the app.

Are there steps I'm missing?  Something I should be doing but am not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a workaround for now - by utilizing the https of Dropbox.  Still investigating as to why hosting it internally (on https site) won't work, but in the meantime the process I outlined above has worked but using an external server (not ideal!).